# Troubles when ordering sql results by multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

```
year  monthnumber  sales
------------------------
2014       8       2800
2014       9       3000
2013      11       2120
2014       8       2700
2013       7       2600
2013      12       2100
```

I need to display all unique combinations of the columns "year" and "monthnumber". I'm having troubles ordering the results so that the most recent combination (september 2014) is displayed first. The results should be:

```
september 2014
august 2014
december 2013
november 2013
july 2013
```

The code below gives me the following results so far (so something goes wrong when ordering the months):

```
september 2014
august 2014
july 2013
december 2013
november 2013
```

**Php/Sql:**

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (case  when monthnumber = '1' then 'january'
                                when monthnumber = '2' then 'february'
                                when monthnumber = '3' then 'march'
                                when monthnumber = '4' then 'april'
                                when monthnumber = '5' then 'may'
                                when monthnumber = '6' then 'june'
                                when monthnumber = '7' then 'july'
                                when monthnumber = '8' then 'august'
                                when monthnumber = '9' then 'september'
                                when monthnumber = '10' then 'october'
                                when monthnumber = '11' then 'november'
                                when monthnumber = '12' then 'december'
                         end) AS monthname, year from `exampletable` ORDER BY year DESC, monthnumber DESC";

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();

 if($stmt->rowCount())
 {
 while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
?>

<?php echo strtolower($result['monthname']);?> <?php echo $result['year'];?>

<?php
 }// end while
 }// end if
 else {
 echo '0 results';
 }// end else
?>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need simple type cast in order by [*demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/409ec/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to cast `MonthNumber` to an `INTEGER` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
ORDER BY year DESC, CAST(monthnumber AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

if MontNumber is a string then the sorting order is done first on the first character and then after that, on the second character; which should give something like the following when sorted by descent order:

9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
12
11
10
1

As stated in the other answer, you must first cast your MonthNumber from a string to an integer.